# How to make a helper function work - please see code below

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a rock, paper, and scissors game that receives input from a user that plays against a robot that randomly selects rock, paper, or scissors. Here is my main() code:

```
"""
    Name: Scott Houston
    Date: January 19th, 2021
    Program Description: Game of classic rock, paps
"""

import random
import gameFunctions2


def main():
    while True:
        computer_move = random.randint(1, 3)
        print("Welcome to rock, paper, scissors! Rock beats scissors, scissors beats paper,"
              " and paper beats rock. ")
        user_input = input("Press 'A' for rock, 'B' for paper, and 'C' for scissors!\n"
                           "A. Rock\n"
                           "B. Paper\n"
                           "C. Scissors\n")

        if gameFunctions2.tie(user_input, computer_move) == False:

            if user_input == "A" or user_input == "a":
                if computer_move == 2:
                    print("Your opponent has chosen paper! Paper wraps rock! You lose! ")
                else:
                    print("Your opponent has chosen scissors! Rock breaks scissors! You win! ")
            elif user_input == "B" or user_input == "b":
                if computer_move == 3:
                    print("Your opponent has chosen scissors! Paper is cut by scissors! You lose! ")
                else:
                    print("Your opponent has chosen rock! Paper wraps rock! You win! ")
            elif user_input == "C" or user_input == "c":
                if computer_move == 1:
                    print("Your opponent has chosen rock! Scissors loses to rock! You lose! ")
                else:
                    print("Your opponent has chosen paper! Scissors beats paper! You win! ")

        if gameFunctions2.input_detection(user_input) == True:
            print()
        else:
            print()

        user_play_again = input("Would you like to play again? Type 'y' if you'd like to play again. ")
        if user_play_again == "y":
            print()
        else:
            print("Have a great day! ")
            break


# Calls the Main Function
main()
```

Here is my helper function (gameFunctions2):

```
def input_detection(user_input):
    if user_input == "A" or user_input == "a" or user_input == "B" or user_input == "b" or user_input == "C" or user_input == "c":
        return True
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid option! ")
        return False


def tie(user_input, computer_move):
    if user_input == user_input.lower in ["a"] and computer_move == "1":
        print("It's a tie!")
        return True
    if user_input == user_input.lower in ["b"] and computer_move == "2":
        print("It's a tie!")
        return True
    if user_input == user_input.lower in ["c"] and computer_move == "3":
        print("It's a tie!")
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The problem that I'm facing right now is that there will never be a tie between the user and the computer. I've tried to implement the function tie(user_input, computer_move) into main(), but to no success. I have to use helper functions for this assignment, so I'm trying my best to do so. Also, if there's any place that I can make my code more efficient, it would be fantastic if you could point out where :))

Comment: `str` "1" is not the same as `int` 1. Change your if statements `computer_move == 1`

Comment: `if user_input == user_input.lower in ["a"]`  The first part results in a bool, (`True` or `False`).

Comment: @Glycerine Oooh, I see! I've fixed that, but it hasn't fixed my main issue ://

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Oh, but I just wanted my code to look better without much code in it. What would you suggest as an alternative rather than listing every possibility out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your tie function to this:

```
def tie(user_input, computer_move):
    if user_input.lower() == "a" and computer_move == 1:
        print("It's a tie!")
        return True
    elif user_input.lower() == "b" and computer_move == 2:
        print("It's a tie!")
        return True
    elif user_input.lower() == "c" and computer_move == 3:
        print("It's a tie!")
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

1. You cant compare `String` and `Int` like this: `computer_move == "1"`  when computer_move is `Int`.
2. Simplify the `user_input.lower() == "a"` statement.

---

Here is what you can use to make your code more readable:

- Use dictionary to translate users input into integers.
- Then you can also easily check all the conditions.

Here is the code (I have only added the part where I have get rid of the `tie` function):

```
import random

choose = "Start"
symbols = {"rock":1, "paper":2, "scissors":3}

while True:
    choose = input("Hi welcome to my game! Choose between Rock, Paper, Scissors! End the game with 'End':\n")
    choose = choose.lower()

    computer = random.randint(1,3)

    if choose in symbols: #Check if input is in a string and if its in symbols
       choose = symbols[choose]
    elif choose == "end":
        break
    else:
        print("You have written down something ... weird ... next round.")
        continue

    if choose == computer:
        print("It's a tie!")
    else:
        #Choose who wins ...
        pass
```

Comment: I will! After the cooldown lol. Do you know where I can make my code more efficient or just look better overall?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of minor issues in your code that can be streamlined and a few major ones, but the one causing your issues is that you are defining `computer_move` as an integer in the main function (`computer_move = random.randint(1, 3)`), but in your tie function, you are comparing it to a string (eg, `computer_move == "1"`) The first half of your if statement also is not doing what you want: Rewrite that function as such:

```py
def tie(user_input, computer_move):
    if user_input.lower() == "a" and computer_move == 1:
        print("It's a tie!")
        return True
    if user_input.lower() == "b" and computer_move == 2:
        print("It's a tie!")
        return True
    if user_input() == "c" and computer_move == 3:
        print("It's a tie!")
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

If you don't want to have a different if statement for each possible outcome, you can try this:

```py
def outcomes(user_input, computer_move):
    end_states = {"tie": [["a", 1], ["b",2], ["c",3]],
                  "user_win": ["LISTS OF USER WIN STATES"]}

    if [user_input.lower(), computer_move] in end_states["tie"]:
        print("tie")
    if [user_input.lower(), computer_move] in end_states["user_win"]:
        print("user wins")
    else:
        print("computer wins")
```

A few of the fixes:

```
user_input = input("Press 'A' for rock, 'B' for paper, and 'C' for scissors!\n"
    "A. Rock\n"
    "B. Paper\n"
    C. Scissors\n")
```

can be changed to:

```py
user_input = input("Press 'A' for rock, 'B' for paper, and 'C' for scissors!\n"
    "A. Rock\n"
    "B. Paper\n"
    C. Scissors\n").lower()
```

so that you don't need to check for both upper and lower cases each time (you would also be able to remove .lower() from the tie function.

You should move the `input_detection` function to right after the user makes the input, and you can rewrite the check as such:

```py
if not gameFunctions2.input_detection(user_input):
    continue
```

Which roughly translates to, if it returns "False", return to the start of your while loop (You can also remove the checks for uppercase and lowercase letters, if you use the previous edit).

For checking if the player wants to play again, add `.lower()` to the end of the input, and you can change the last lines as such:

```py
if user_play_again != "y":
    print("Have a great day! ")
    break
```

You don't need to have a statement that evaluates `if user_play_again == "y"` just to have the else statement (unless you want there to be a separate action for it). You can evaluate the opposite (`if user_play_again != "y"`) alone.

As I began to do earlier, you can put each ending variation into dictionaries and instead of having a different line for each end state check, you can evaluate the dictionary as a whole to streamline things a bit too.

These might not be the only things, and others might disagree with my changes, but it's a start of how I would rewrite the code.

Comment: Thank you! I understand where I went wrong now :) Is there any places in my code that I can improve in terms of efficiency and just looking neat overall?

Comment: Oh yeah, can you let me know what the major and minor issues are? I'd like to get a 100% on this assignment

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have resolved the bugs in your code. This answer is meant to give you some ideas about how you might do things differently - specifically, a more object-oriented approach, and taking advantage of the standard library a bit more.

```
from enum import Enum

class Move(Enum):
    ROCK = 0
    PAPER = 1
    SCISSOR = 2


def get_user_move():

    moves = dict(zip("ABC", Move))

    print("Options:")
    for option, move in moves.items():
        print(f"{option:>5}. {move.name.title()}")

    prompt = "Enter your selection: "
    
    while True:
        user_input = input(prompt).upper()
        if user_input in moves:
            break
        prompt = "Try again: "
    return moves[user_input]  

def main():

    from random import choice

    while True:
        user_move = get_user_move()
        computer_move = choice(tuple(Move))

        print(f"\nYou picked {user_move.name.title()}")
        print(f"The computer picked {computer_move.name.title()}")

        if user_move is computer_move:
            print("It's a tie!\n")
        else:
            winner = ("The computer", "You")[(computer_move.value + 1) % len(Move) is user_move.value]
            print(f"The winner is: {winner}!\n")

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```